# check first with timestamp?

Tags: cocoa

do i save some time when having a timestamp and only ask the operation isCancelled every 50 msec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isCancelled` is a pretty simple `BOOL` flag, so checking it on each iteration of even a very tight loop doesn't incur a real performance penalty. I think you'll find the overhead of setting up a mechanism to check `isCancelled` periodically will actually perform worse.